# Redirecting in Firefox failing

Tags: php, session, redirect, header

So far, I have coded my website to display the login page (using GET data) through:
website?q=account&req=login

If they are authenticated, it redirects using PHP header() them to the account page:
website?q=account

For some reason I come up with a 'The page isn't redirecting properly' message on Firefox, where Internet Explorer seems to work... Here's the code snippet:

```
case 'account':
    if($req=="login") {
        if($user->isLoggedIn())
            header("Location: /?p=account");
        else {
            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

                $form_data = array('username' => $_POST['username'], 'password' => $_POST['password']);

                $user->login($form_data);
                if($user->isLoggedIn()) {
                    header("Location: /?p=account");
                }
            }

            $pagearr=array('css' => "login.css", 'content' => "login.php");
        }

    }
    else {
        if(!$user->isLoggedIn()) 
            header("Location: /?p=account&req=login");
    }
break;
```

And below is a snippet of my User class:

```
    function User() {
        session_start();

        $this->user_id = isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ? $_SESSION['user_id'] : null;

        if($this->user_id) {
            $database= new Database;
            if($database->checkUserSession($this->user_id,session_id())) {
                $this->logged_in=true;
            }
            else {
                $this->addSessionError('global','Your login session has timed out, you may login by <a href="/syn/?p=account&req=login">clicking here</a>.');
                unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
            }
        }
    }
```

The user is authenticated successfully (if I return to the home page, it displays that they are logged in), what have I done wrong?

Comment: Maybe there is something printed before the headers are set. Or.. have you set ob_start()?

Comment: The kind of error you are experiencing suggest a redirect "loop", wherein this page is redirecting to a page that ends up redirecting back to this page, etc.

Comment: Call `exit()` explicitly after `header("Location...");` to prevent the script executing further.

Comment: Jose: I haven't used ob_start(), cale_b: I've added the else clause that shows what happens when $req is invalid/empty.

Comment: Tommy... what happens in other browsers?

Comment: In Internet Explorer, it takes me to /?p=account as expected, in Firefox I receive the 'The page isn't redirecting properly' message.

Comment: Do what Michael suggest. But maybe instead of writing it every time, use a function. function redir($url){ header('Location: ' . $redir); exit(); }

Comment: exit() didn't solve it... I still have the Firefox issues. It seems as if the infinite redirect happens when they are logged in every time on /?p=account&req=login

Answer (score 0):

I figured that the overuse of header() is not great practice for this scenario, so I made 'account' and 'login' within the same GET field, and then checking to see if the user is logged in to display the right includes.

```
case 'account':
    $pagearr=array('css' => "login.css", 'content' => "login.php");

    if($user->isLoggedIn()) 
        $pagearr=array('css' => "account.css", 'content' => "account.php");
    else {
        $pagearr=array('css' => "login.css", 'content' => "login.php");

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

            $form_data = array('username' => $_POST['username'], 'password' => $_POST['password']);

            if($user->login($form_data)) {
                $pagearr=array('css' => "account.css", 'content' => "account.php");
            }
        }           
    }
break;
```

Thanks for the help guys!